# jQuery : Selection doesn't get set

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a selection from a dropdown list via jQuery

Here's the dropdown code

```
<select id="someid_ddlPaymentMode" class="selectpicker" name="someid_ddlPaymentMode" tabindex="-98">
<option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="123" selected="selected">Cash</option>
<option selected="selected" value="456">Transaction Transfer</option>
</select>
```

asp.net where the event is triggered

```
onchange="changePaymentMode(event,this)"
```

and here's the jQuery , I've been trying again and again this code works the first time and when I set to get Text it does get the text

```
function changePaymentMode(evt, obj){

          var isMoreThan2000 = 2000;
          var requiredAmount = $("input[id$='txtRquiredAmount']");

          console.log(requiredAmount.val());

          if(parseInt(requiredAmount.val()) < isMoreThan2000)
          {
              console.log("true");
              var s = $('[id$=ddlPaymentMode] option:nth-child(2)').attr("selected", "selected").text();  //verification purpose : gets the text 
              console.log(s)
              //$('[id$=ddlPaymentMode] option:nth-child(2)').attr("selected", "selected").text(); // <-- doesn't select
          }     

        }
```

Any reason why the text is not set?

Comment: There does not appear to be an element having `id` ending with `dplPaymentMode` at `html`? Are you trying to select `#PaymentMode` element?

Comment: I've made some changes , basically this is a lighter version. ddlPaymentMode is the ending and not #PaymentMode element.Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I notice you have selected="selected" on more than one option, normally this should only go on one option, unless your <select> is set to "multiple" mode.

Comment: Are you trying to select `<option selected="selected" value="456">Transaction Transfer</option>` with `:nth-child(2)`?

Comment: @guest271314 yup that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Have you tried `javascript` at Answer which utilizes `:eq()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the browser sets the `selected` attribute on items when you select them. You can however use the `:selected` selector on the options in the `select` elements like `select#someid_ddlPaymentMode option:selected`. And then get the value of that.

See here for more info: https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector `$("> option:eq(2)", this)` where `this` is `context` : the current element where `change` event was fired, `>` followed by space character selects children of current `context`; substituted `:eq()` for `:nth-child()`

```
function changePaymentMode(event) {

  var isMoreThan2000 = 2000;

  if (1 < isMoreThan2000) {
    console.log("true");
    var s = $('> option:eq(2)', this).attr("selected", "selected").text();
    //verification purpose : gets the text 
    console.log(s)
  }

}

$("[id$=ddlPaymentMode]").change(changePaymentMode);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/480c0m7q/2